# Update table from another table with Select statement and aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update

Below is schema of my two tables in SQL Server 2008

```
Table 1

StartDate,EndDate,ID,country

Table 2

StartDate,EndDate,ID,country
```

I want to update Table 1 like below

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.startdate=min(t2.startdate),
    t1.enddate=max(t2.enddate) 
FROM table1      t1,
     table 2 t2
WHERE t1.country=t2.country 
GROUP BY t2.country
```

Currently I am using sub queries to update startdate and enddate but I didn't like that.

Kindly Suggest some better solution

Comment: Error on group by error message is "Incorrect syntax near group by"

Comment: `Update t1 set t1.startdate=min(t2.startdate),t1.enddate=max(t2.enddate) from table1 t1 inner join table 2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID where t1.country=t2.country group by t2.country`

Comment: check my updated answer, please add sql-server tag on your question

Comment: check again ;) I hope this is the final :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose SQL 2008 is Sql Server 2008. Because UPDATE ... FROM is not standard ANSI but works only on Sql Server

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
update table1
set table1.startdate=t.l,
table1.enddate=t.u
from
    (select MAX(t2.startdate) as l, MAX(t2.enddate) as u, t2.idcountry as idc
    from table2 t2
    where t2.idcountry = table1.idcountry
    group by t2.idcountry) as t
where table1.idcountry = t.idc
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Error message is "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."

Comment: It will update each and every row with same min and max dates.

Comment: Yup I figured that out. Thanks anyways.